# prove $ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} (1+x)^{\frac {1}{x} } = e $ by epsilon delta?

Tags: calculus

Title says it all. How do we prove that $ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} (1+x)^{\frac {1}{x} } = e $ by epsilon delta?

Comment: How do you define $e$ ?

Comment: $ e = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {1}{k!} \approx 2.71828 $

Comment: How is $(1+x)^{1/x}$ defined?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest showing that $(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$ is continuous at $x=0$, this shouldnt be too hard. Then you can use that a continuous function is also sequentially continuous and plug in $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ as sequence which converges to zero and you get the usual expression $e=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}$. If you dont know this expression yet, its also not too hard to prove using the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the limit exists, then it equals $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+\frac{1}{n})^n$. It equals 
$$
(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=1+{n\choose 0} \frac{1}{n^0} + {n\choose 1} \frac{1}{n^1} +\ldots= \frac{1}{0!} + \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} \frac{(n-1)}{n} + \frac{1}{3!}\frac{n-1}{n}\frac{n-2}{n} +\ldots
$$
It shouldn't be hard to check that for $n\to\infty$, this converges to your sum of inverse factorials.